# Return a new thymeleaf page fragment and some file from spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Tell me how to properly implement the spring controller. I want it to return a new thymeleafe page fragment and Excel file at the same time.

I know how to implement a controller to return a page fragment:

```
@GetMapping("/some_url")
public String updateFragment(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("attribute", someAtribute);
    return "some_page :: fragment";
}
```

And I know how to implement a controller for downloading files:

```
@GetMapping("some_url")
public void getReport(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = "attachment; filename=file.xlsx";
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("path_to_file"));
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        int row = 12;
        Row exampleRow = sheet.getRow(12);
        int count = 1;
        for (SIZForKomplex s : objectList) {
            if (s.getNumber() != 0) {
                sheet.getRow(row).setRowStyle(exampleRow.getRowStyle());
                sheet.getRow(row).setHeight(exampleRow.getHeight());

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    sheet.getRow(row).getCell(i).setCellStyle(exampleRow.getCell(i).getCellStyle());
                }
                sheet.getRow(row).getCell(0).setCellValue(count);
                sheet.getRow(row).getCell(1).setCellValue(s.getNomenclatureNumber());
                sheet.getRow(row).getCell(2).setCellValue(s.getNamesiz());
                sheet.getRow(row).getCell(3).setCellValue(s.getSize());
                sheet.getRow(row).getCell(4).setCellValue(s.getHeight());
                sheet.getRow(row).getCell(5).setCellValue(s.getNumber());
                sheet.getRow(row).getCell(6).setCellValue(sizRepository.findById(s.getId()).orElseThrow().getEd_izm());
                sheet.getRow(row).getCell(7).setCellValue(" ");
                row++;
                count++;
            }
        }

        inputStream.close();

        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException | EncryptedDocumentException
            ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But how do I combine this. I need to update the data on the page and download the Excel file

Comment: You cannot. You can only do one of both not both together at the same time.

Comment: Is there another way to download the file and update the data, please tell me?

Comment: No there isn't. You cannot do 2 things in 1 go. You ask a question (the incoming request) and you can get only 1 answer (the response) not 2. So you need 2 requests to do this so you can get 2 answers.